# I'm an absolute beginner in Flutter, how can I achieve this layout?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

I tried with the stack but I couldn't achieve the layout.

[LAYOUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR6Aw.png)

Comment: Please share some code, what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this on.

```
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String pageId;

  const Page1({Key? key, this.pageId = ""}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("UI"),),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                margin:  EdgeInsets.only(top:20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      child: Text("Right"),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      child: Text("Wrong"),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Container(
                  height: 40,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  child: Text("Choose"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Lucifer Please try out my code.

Just copy and paste this code in your android studio

```
Container(
          height: 100,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  width: Get.width * 0.8,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                        child: Text("Right"),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                        child: Text("Right"),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                left: 0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                    child: Text("Choose"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code hope it helpful to you in below code I have used **Stack, Container, Positioned Widgets**

```
 Container(
            height: 100,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                          child: Text("Right"),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                          child: Text("Wrong"),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      child: Text("Choose"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Your Layout Look like this -> [image]